# Unrecognized selector sent to instance (Without Storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have been coding an app programmatically without using a storyboard.

Thus I believe this "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error has nothing to do with some broken linkage between buttons and other objects.

On my home page, I'm loading a view from another class "YourPicksVC"

```
-(void)loadYourPicks{

yourPickView1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
YourPicksVC *ypVC = [[YourPicksVC alloc]init];
[ypVC initYourPicks];
yourPickView1 = ypVC.yourPicksView;

[pageDisplay addSubview:yourPickView1];
}
```

In the class yourPicksVC, I have inside the function "initYourPicks"

```
restaurants = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[restaurants setTitle:@"Restaurants" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[restaurants setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
restaurants.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
restaurants.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[restaurants setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
[restaurants addTarget:self action:@selector(restaurantCategories) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
restaurants.frame = CGRectMake(20, 70, 100, 50);
[yourPicksView addSubview:restaurants];
```

Since I was debugging my code, I simply have

```
-(void)restaurantCategories{

NSLog(@"very nice");
restaurantsView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 568, 100, 518)];
[yourPicksView addSubview:restaurantsView];

}
```

This is the message that I receive:

```
   2014-05-20 18:33:59.037 Ally[19839:70b] -[__NSCFType restaurantCategories]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94bfec0
   2014-05-20 18:33:59.039 Ally[19839:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType restaurantCategories]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94bfec0'
   *** First throw call stack:
   (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x027615e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cb08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x027fe903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0275190b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x027514ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cc2874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
6   UIKit                               0x00a200c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
7   UIKit                               0x00a2004e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
8   UIKit                               0x00b180c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
9   UIKit                               0x00b18484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
10  UIKit                               0x00b17733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
11  UIKit                               0x00a5d51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
12  UIKit                               0x00a5e184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
13  UIKit                               0x00a31e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
14  UIKit                               0x00a1c18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
15  CoreFoundation                      0x026ea83f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x026ea1cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0270729e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
18  CoreFoundation                      0x02706ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
19  CoreFoundation                      0x027068db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
20  GraphicsServices                    0x035b89e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
21  GraphicsServices                    0x035b8809 GSEventRun + 104
22  UIKit                               0x00a1ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
23  Ally                                0x0000c24d main + 141
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02ca2701 start + 1
   )
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please let me know where I have done wrong. I have tried similar way of doing in my other apps, and it worked fine.

```
-(void)loadYourPicks1{

result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

yourPicksView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, result.height-50)];
[yourPicksView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

restaurants = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[restaurants setTitle:@"Restaurants" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[restaurants setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
restaurants.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
restaurants.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[restaurants setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
[restaurants addTarget:self action:@selector(restaurantCategories) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
restaurants.frame = CGRectMake(20, 70, 100, 50);
[yourPicksView addSubview:restaurants];
//TASK: Each time we click on one of the buttons, more detailed categories will show up!

bars = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[bars setTitle:@"Bars" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bars setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
bars.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
bars.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[bars setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
bars.enabled = YES;
[bars addTarget:self action:@selector(barCategories) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
bars.frame = CGRectMake(20, 215, 100, 50);

hairSalon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[hairSalon setTitle:@"Hair Salons" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[hairSalon setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
hairSalon.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
hairSalon.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[hairSalon setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
hairSalon.enabled = YES;
[hairSalon addTarget:self action:@selector(lol) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
hairSalon.frame = CGRectMake(20, 145, 100, 50);

nailSpa = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[nailSpa setTitle:@"Nail Spas" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nailSpa setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
nailSpa.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
nailSpa.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[nailSpa setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
nailSpa.enabled = YES;
nailSpa.frame = CGRectMake(20, 285, 100, 50);

health = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[health setTitle:@"Health" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[health setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
health.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
health.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[health setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
health.enabled = YES;
health.frame = CGRectMake(20, 355, 100, 50);

massage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[massage setTitle:@"Massage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[massage setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
massage.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
massage.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[massage setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
massage.enabled = YES;
massage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 425, 100, 50);


[yourPicksView addSubview:bars];
[yourPicksView addSubview:coffeeShops];
[yourPicksView addSubview:nailSpa];
[yourPicksView addSubview:hairSalon];
[yourPicksView addSubview:health];
[yourPicksView addSubview:massage];

}
```

Comment: In what class is the method `-restaurantCategories` implemented?

Comment: It is implemented in the same class as the button, which is initYourPicks, which is in the class yourPicksVC

Comment: Sounds like you've implemented `initYourPicks` incorrectly. Pls show that code. Is it the class's initializer? If not, you MUST give it a different name; names beginning with `init` are reserved. If it _is_ the initializer, it may not be property constructed.

Comment: Google "__NSCFType" (like you should have done before asking this question).  You did `addTarget:self` to your `restaurants` object, but didn't do `removeTarget` before `self` was deleted.

Comment: @HotLicks, what exactly do you mean? I have never encountered such problem before :S

Comment: @matt, I have changed the initYourPicks to loadYourPicks1, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Some is sending a message "restaurantCategories". Must be your code. Who is sending it, and who is it sent to? Find that in your code. Set a breakpoint where the message is sent, and start debugging. BTW. instance variables should start with an underscore character. That makes your code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in here -

```
-(void)loadYourPicks{

  yourPickView1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
  YourPicksVC *ypVC = [[YourPicksVC alloc]init];
  [ypVC initYourPicks];
  yourPickView1 = ypVC.yourPicksView;

  [pageDisplay addSubview:yourPickView1];
}
```

You are allocated your `YourPicksVC` as a local variable in the `loadYourPicks` method.  You are adding the `UIView` from the `YourPicksVC` as a subview to to `pageDisplay`, so `pageDisplay` will hold a strong reference to the `UIView` and prevent it from being deallocated.  Unfortunately nothing is holding a strong reference to the `YourPicksVC` itself, so when `loadYourPicks` returns the `YourPicksVC` object will get deallocated.  some time later you touch the button and invoke the `restaurantCategories` selector, but the memory that used to contain your `YourPicksVC` has been deallocated and reallocated to a different object - in this case a `__NSCFType`, which doesn't understand the `restaurantCategories` selector so you get an exception.

If you create a property to hold your `YourPicksVC`

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) YourPicksVC *ypVC;
```

and use that in your code then the view controller won't get deallocated -

```
-(void)loadYourPicks{

  yourPickView1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
  self.ypVC = [[YourPicksVC alloc]init];
  [self.ypVC initYourPicks];
  yourPickView1 = self.ypVC.yourPicksView;

  [pageDisplay addSubview:yourPickView1];
}
```

If you had searched for "__NSCFType unrecognised selector" you would have found that it is commonly caused by invalid references to deallocated objects, which was the hint that HotLicks was trying to give you.